# Python 3 permutations Scrabble

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm struggling a bit with an effective way of debugging Python, and the consequent lack of understanding and optimization.

I'm in the process of writing a Scrabble game in Python as an experiment, and I suspect I'm going about it all wrong. Namely, I'm failing to understand how to handle the blank tiles (represented by question marks below). I've bungled the code as follows:

```
import itertools
import string

  rack = 'rstlena??'
  blank_count = rack.count('?')
  letters = rack.split(',')
  word_set = set()

  if blank_count > 0:
    rack = rack.replace('?', '')
    if blank_count == 1:
      for l in string.ascii_lowercase:
        letters.append(rack + l)
    elif blank_count == 2:
      for l in string.ascii_lowercase:
        letters.append(rack + l + l)

    for l_combo in rack:
      for i in range(3, 9):
        for permutation in itertools.permutations(l_combo, i):
          word_to_check = ''.join(permutation)
          if word_to_check in word_list: # word_list is some dictionary
            word_set.add(word_to_check)
```

...

It works when there's one blank, but with two it just adds the same letter and produces undesired results (obviously).

I apologize in advance for the ugly code I've subjected you to cringe at.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It's why I'm asking the question.Thank you also for down-voting the question on those grounds.

Comment: Well, you can just do another `for l in string.ascii_lowercase:` loop inside the first one (just change `l` to another variable name) and get two different letters. I did not downvote the question, btw.

Comment: If I can improve my question so I can avoid further criticism/down-voting, I'll do everything I can.

Comment: Hmm. Okay. So I have misunderstood the scope in other words?

Comment: Where exactly would I place that additional loop, if I may ask? And thank you for your help.

Comment: Just inside the first one, so that you have `elif blank_count == 2: \\ for l in string.ascii_lowercase: \\ for l2 in string.ascii_lowercase: \\ letters.append(rack + l + l2)` I'm working your code, I'll try to give you something that works (preferably reasonably fast).

Comment: The way your code is done, if you have two jokers that mean you have 676 possible racks, and you are going through every permutation for all of them, even when a lot of permutations are going to be the same between racks. That is going to be veeeeery slow, and I don't really have any clever idea to speed that up.

Comment: The line `letters = rack.split(',')` can't possibly do anything useful, since there are no commas in `rack`. Is this really the code you're running?

Comment: I'm the first to admit that my Python really sucks.

Comment: I'm having a horrible time debugging, and that very well might be a different question altogether. I'd love to harness the power and efficiency that is Python.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, and be acceptably fast. I tried to comment the tricky parts, do not hesitate to ask if there are some bits of the code you do not understand.

```
import itertools
import string
import numpy as np

#takes a list of words as input ['door', 'chair', 'wall'], and returns the words alphabetically sorted [['door', 'door'], ['achir', 'chair'], ['allw', 'wall']]
def sortWordList(word_list):
    return np.array([["".join(sorted(word)), word] for word in word_list])

#recursive function to get all unordered n-letter subsets of `letters`, without repetition. NLetterSubsets(2, "fly") == ["fl", "fy", "ly"]; NLetterSubsets(2, "foo") == ["fo", "fo", "oo"]
def NLetterSubsets(n, letters):
    if n == len(letters):
        return [letters]
    if n > len(letters) or len(letters) == 0:
        return []
    return [letters[0] + x for x in NLetterSubsets(n-1, letters[1:])] + NLetterSubsets(n, letters[1:])

#loads word_list from a newline-separated file
def loadWordList(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]

word_list = loadWordList('words.txt')
word_list = sortWordList(word_list)
print(word_list)

rack = 'trackable'
blank_count = rack.count('?')
if blank_count:
    rack = rack.replace('?','')
word_set = set()

#possible letters is the list of all possible values taken by the blank(s)
possibleLetters = ['']
if blank_count >= 1:
    possibleLetters += [l for l in string.ascii_lowercase]
if blank_count == 2:
    possibleLetters += [l+m for l in string.ascii_lowercase for m in string.ascii_lowercase]

for blanks in possibleLetters:
    for i in range(3-len(blanks), 9-len(blanks)):
        #gets a subset of letters from rack, to which we will add the blank values to form a word of length in range(3,9)
        for setOfLetter in NLetterSubsets(i-blank_count, rack):
            sortedWordToSearchFor = ''.join(sorted(setOfLetter + blanks))
            #if the sorted list of letters we have is also present in the word_set, then take the associated word
            for index in np.where(word_list[:,0] == sortedWordToSearchFor)[0]:
                word_set.add(word_list[index][1])

print(word_set)
```

Comment: Pardon me, but I'm still a bit lost with some code that doesn't work. It may be that the [word_list] is somewhat confusing and/or out of place. I apologize if I'm just showing my ignorance.

Comment: There is no problem in asking questions on a site made for asking questions. The above code runs fine on my computer. If you get an error when running the code, please provide the log otherwise there is nothing I can do.

Comment: I've just tried it with a `word_list` of 355k English words, it takes 4.4 seconds without any blank, which is quite reasonably fast, and 63 seconds with one, which is quite less fast. By interpolating, I guess this will take at least 10 minutes with two, but I have no clue on how to make it any faster. Nevertheless, this code works, I suggest you take it to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), they should be able to speed it up there.

Comment: Just tried it with 2 blanks, it takes 12 minutes :(